# NullPointerException on a Spring bean successfully injected

Tags: java, spring, properties

I'm trying to use property files with Spring. Files injection works fine and I have access to my bean. 
For instance, this code

```
    @Autowired
    private Properties properties;
```

gives me this error : `No qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: csvHeaderProperties,systemProperties`.

When I inject properties using resource, I get no error and everything seems fine :

```
@Component
public Class MyClass {

    @Resource(name="csvHeaderProperties")
    private Properties properties;
}
```

However, this code gives me a NPE :

```
@Component
public class DynCSVService {

    @Autowired
    private DynCSVDictionnary headerDico;

    public void processFile() {
        System.out.println(headerDico);
        }
}
```

Both files are located in the same package.
Is there something wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error : it was in another file where I didn't inject DynCSVService, I used the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

How should Spring deduce which one to insert?

You have to name it if there are two or more possible matches for injection.

Answer (score 0):

You should use @Named annotation

Here is an example

```
@Named("userDAO")
public class EfaUserDAOImpl
```

And inject it where you need;

```
@Inject
private @Named("userDAO")
EfaUserDAO userDAO;
```